# Dynamically create class that mocks another class (like remotingProxy) in haxe

Tags: haxe

I want to be able to dynamically create a new class that has all of the methods of another class. In particular, I want to make my own kind of remoting proxy.
class ApiProxy extends haxe.remoting.Proxy { }
The new class ApiProxy would have all of the same method names and signatures as Api, and would be compile time checked. Only every invocation is done over the wire, instead of handled locally.

I think that remoting.Proxy is a magic internal class - is this true? Do regular users have the ability to define a class that is as powerfully static as this? I've never seen this done in Java and I'm impressed with it's capabilities in Haxe.

How would I implement my own class like remoting.Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

haxe.remoting.Proxy is indeed "magic", it is described that way in the source comments:
http://code.google.com/p/haxe/source/browse/trunk/std/haxe/remoting/Proxy.hx?r=3592

You can't replicate with "normal" haxe code. Adding/modifying functionality to haxe.remoting.Proxy for your own class will be difficult, but maybe not impossible.
 Check the tutorial for the "equivalent" api implementing code:
http://haxe.org/doc/remoting/proxy

However, something like this is probably possible with macros:
http://haxe.org/manual/macros

Working with macros is challenging right now.  There is little in the way of documentation or examples, and the macro feature is still under development.  However, it lets you have a some control over the compiler during the compilation process, which can be amazingly useful at times.

good luck!

Comment: I tried making a parent class with empty implementation methods (not an interface), then on the client, I tried instantiating an instance of the parent, and looping through all methods, attempting to replace them with calls across the network, but I couldn't replace the methods with new ones - even if I declared the methods dynamic. This could easily be done if I could just replace methods dynamically. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Declaring the methods dynamic should work. Can you show some code?

Comment: Yeah, if you're just overwriting dynamic fields, this should work ok.  You might consider overriding a few methods for the instance, rather than the entire instance in this case.  Reflect.fields, and the Type methods sometimes will return hidden (secret) fields that you may not want to proxy.   I have a utility class/method called "Glue" that lets you combine functions in a type safe way: http://scwn.net/2009/10/09/function-decoration-in-haxe-glue/

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll try to get something broken to show you.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with macros

take a look at this post to get the idea:

http://haxe.1354130.n2.nabble.com/Macros-Are-Awesome-tc5945711.html

You can write, save to filesystem and register a new Class inside of a Macro, based on type information that was passed to the function.

Comment: FYI, the link shared inside that forum post is dead now (https://gist.github.com/788833 no longer exists on Github) :(